# Express.js + Mongoose. find() not passing results for defined variable

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am trying to set items to be viewed only by the user that posted it. I'm using Passport.js to take care of the sessions. In this code I am  able to see everything successfully run up until the end.

```
     app.get('/latestproject', isLoggedIn, function(req, res) { 
        var Project = require('../app/models/project');
        var latest = null;
        var currentUser = req.user._id;
        Project.find({owner: currentUser}).sort({_id: 'desc'}).limit(1).exec(
            function(err, projects) {
                if (err) {
                    res.send(err);
                } else if (projects) {
                    latest = projects._id
                    res.redirect('/project/' + latest);
                } else {
                    res.redirect('/start');
                }

            });
});
```

I've been able to run this identical code with no problems without the user component. The owner value in the database is the same as what is being output by the currentUser variable.

Everything seems to work fine but for some reason by the time it makes it down the pipe to my conditionals,  I get "project/undefined" in the console log as my final result.

*I know it's probably something small, but I've been going for hours and I need help!*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is small mistake in your code. Normally mongoose `find` returns an array of objects even if the result count is 1. So change your code to this

```
else if (projects && projects.length===1) {
                latest = projects[0]._id
                res.redirect('/project/' + latest);
            }
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! This was a great learning lesson. Cheers!

Comment: Cool Bro.. All the best